# Opencv Python-3.5.2 Face Recognition

Tags: opencv, python-3.5

I am working on Face Recognition. My code was working fine but the results were not that good so I did a little revision and along with some amendements, I updated my **opencv-python from 3.4.3 to 3.4.4** and same for the **opencv-contrib-python**. And now I am getting syntax errors.

```
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

Error: cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.4) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

And also,

```
cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'
```

I didn't get any Errors like this before but after updating, I am getting these. What's the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go back to the previous version and try.

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-python==3.4.3
```

the same as opencv-contrib-python.
Then see if your code works.